# Work with tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have this list of tuples:

```
dCF3=[((0.0, 0.0), (0.100000001490116, 0.0), (0.200000002980232, 0.0), (0.300000011920929, 0.0), (0.400000005960464, 0.0), (0.5, 0.0), (0.600000023841858, 0.0), (0.699999988079071, 0.0), (0.800000011920929, 0.0), (0.899999976158142, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0)), ((0.0, 0.0), (0.00249999994412065, -268.749877929688), (0.00499999988824129, -534.530700683594), (0.0087500000372529, -932.520874023438), (0.0143750002607703, -1527.93103027344), (0.0228125005960464, -2414.58032226563), (0.0328124985098839, -3408.89599609375), (0.0428125001490116, -4313.58447265625), (0.0528125017881393, -5153.6572265625), (0.0628124997019768, -6001.00244140625), (0.0728124976158142, -6861.203125), (0.0828125029802322, -7718.9912109375), (0.0928125008940697, -8568.873046875), (0.102812498807907, -9406.283203125), (0.112812496721745, -10222.2841796875), (0.122812502086163, -11016.26953125), (0.1328125, -11787.7470703125), (0.142812505364418, -12536.3466796875), (0.152812495827675, -13261.8193359375), (0.162812501192093, -13964.04296875), (0.172812506556511, -14643.01953125), (0.182812497019768, -15298.8681640625), (0.192812502384186, -15931.8173828125), (0.202812492847443, -16542.1953125), (0.212812498211861, -17130.41796875), (0.222812503576279, -17696.978515625), (0.232812494039536, -18242.431640625), (0.242812499403954, -18767.3828125), (0.252812504768372, -19272.4765625), (0.262812495231628, -19758.388671875), (0.272812485694885, -20225.806640625), (0.282812505960464, -20675.43359375), (0.292812496423721, -21107.970703125), (0.302812486886978, -21523.888671875), (0.312812507152557, -21923.1015625), (0.322812497615814, -22307.275390625), (0.332812488079071, -22677.072265625), (0.34281250834465, -23033.1328125), (0.352812498807907, -23376.078125), (0.362812489271164, -23706.50390625), (0.372812509536743, -24024.984375), (0.3828125, -24332.06640625), (0.392812490463257, -24628.27734375), (0.402812510728836, -24914.11328125), (0.412812501192093, -25190.052734375), (0.42281249165535, -25456.55078125), (0.432812511920929, -25714.037109375), (0.442812502384186, -25962.919921875), (0.452812492847443, -26203.58984375), (0.462812513113022, -26436.4140625), (0.472812503576279, -26661.74609375), (0.482812494039536, -26879.9140625), (0.492812514305115, -27091.232421875), (0.502812504768372, -27296.00390625), (0.512812495231628, -27494.9765625), (0.522812485694885, -27688.0859375), (0.532812476158142, -27875.443359375), (0.542812526226044, -28057.2890625), (0.552812516689301, -28233.853515625), (0.562812507152557, -28405.35546875), (0.572812497615814, -28571.99609375), (0.582812488079071, -28733.9765625), (0.592812478542328, -28891.48046875), (0.602812528610229, -29044.685546875), (0.612812519073486, -29193.7578125), (0.622812509536743, -29338.859375), (0.6328125, -29480.142578125), (0.642812490463257, -29617.75), (0.652812480926514, -29751.8203125), (0.662812471389771, -29882.486328125), (0.672812521457672, -30009.87109375), (0.682812511920929, -30134.09375), (0.692812502384186, -30255.271484375), (0.702812492847443, -30373.5078125), (0.712812483310699, -30488.91015625), (0.722812473773956, -30601.576171875), (0.732812523841858, -30711.599609375), (0.742812514305115, -30819.0703125), (0.752812504768372, -30924.076171875), (0.762812495231628, -31026.69921875), (0.772812485694885, -31127.01953125), (0.782812476158142, -31225.109375), (0.792812526226044, -31321.044921875), (0.802812516689301, -31414.892578125), (0.812812507152557, -31506.720703125), (0.822812497615814, -31596.591796875), (0.832812488079071, -31684.568359375), (0.842812478542328, -31770.70703125), (0.852812528610229, -31855.06640625), (0.862812519073486, -31937.69921875), (0.872812509536743, -32018.658203125), (0.8828125, -32097.9921875), (0.892812490463257, -32175.75), (0.902812480926514, -32251.9765625), (0.912812471389771, -32326.716796875), (0.922812521457672, -32400.013671875), (0.932812511920929, -32471.91015625), (0.942812502384186, -32542.44140625), (0.952812492847443, -32611.6484375), (0.962812483310699, -32679.568359375), (0.972812473773956, -32746.234375), (0.982812523841858, -32811.6796875), (0.992812514305115, -32875.9453125), (1.00281250476837, -32939.05078125), (1.01281249523163, -33001.03515625), (1.02281248569489, -33061.92578125), (1.03281247615814, -33121.75390625), (1.0428124666214, -33180.5390625), (1.05281245708466, -33238.31640625), (1.06281244754791, -33295.10546875), (1.07281255722046, -33350.9375), (1.08281254768372, -33405.83203125), (1.09281253814697, -33459.8125), (1.10281252861023, -33512.90234375), (1.11281251907349, -33565.12109375), (1.12281250953674, -33616.49609375), (1.1328125, -33667.0390625), (1.14281249046326, -33716.77734375), (1.15281248092651, -33765.7265625), (1.16281247138977, -33813.90625), (1.17281246185303, -33861.33203125), (1.18281245231628, -33908.0234375), (1.19281244277954, -33953.99609375), (1.20281255245209, -33999.26953125), (1.21281254291534, -34043.85546875), (1.2228125333786, -34087.76953125), (1.23281252384186, -34131.03125), (1.24281251430511, -34173.65234375), (1.25281250476837, -34215.64453125), (1.26281249523163, -34257.0234375), (1.27281248569489, -34297.8046875), (1.28281247615814, -34338.0), (1.2928124666214, -34377.6171875), (1.30281245708466, -34416.67578125), (1.31281244754791, -34455.18359375), (1.32281255722046, -34493.1484375), (1.33281254768372, -34530.58984375), (1.34281253814697, -34567.515625), (1.35281252861023, -34603.9296875), (1.36281251907349, -34639.8515625), (1.37281250953674, -34675.2890625), (1.3828125, -34710.25), (1.39281249046326, -34744.7421875), (1.40281248092651, -34778.78125), (1.41281247138977, -34812.3671875), (1.42281246185303, -34845.515625), (1.43281245231628, -34878.234375), (1.44281244277954, -34910.53125), (1.45281255245209, -34942.41015625), (1.46281254291534, -34973.88671875), (1.4728125333786, -35004.9609375), (1.48281252384186, -35035.64453125), (1.49281251430511, -35065.9453125), (1.50281250476837, -35095.8671875), (1.51281249523163, -35125.421875), (1.52281248569489, -35154.61328125), (1.53281247615814, -35183.4453125), (1.5428124666214, -35211.9296875), (1.55281245708466, -35240.0703125), (1.56281244754791, -35267.87109375), (1.57281255722046, -35295.34375), (1.58281254768372, -35322.4921875), (1.59281253814697, -35349.31640625), (1.60281252861023, -35375.828125), (1.61281251907349, -35402.03125), (1.62281250953674, -35427.9296875), (1.6328125, -35453.53515625), (1.64281249046326, -35478.84375), (1.65281248092651, -35503.86328125), (1.66281247138977, -35528.6015625), (1.67281246185303, -35553.05859375), (1.68281245231628, -35577.24609375), (1.69281244277954, -35601.16015625), (1.70281255245209, -35624.8125), (1.71281254291534, -35648.203125), (1.7228125333786, -35671.33984375), (1.73281252384186, -35694.22265625), (1.74281251430511, -35716.859375), (1.75281250476837, -35739.25), (1.76281249523163, -35761.40234375), (1.77281248569489, -35783.31640625), (1.78281247615814, -35805.0), (1.7928124666214, -35826.45703125), (1.80281245708466, -35847.6875), (1.81281244754791, -35868.6953125), (1.82281255722046, -35889.484375), (1.83281254768372, -35910.0625), (1.84281253814697, -35930.42578125), (1.85281252861023, -35950.58203125), (1.86281251907349, -35970.53125), (1.87281250953674, -35990.28125), (1.8828125, -36009.83203125), (1.89281249046326, -36029.1875), (1.90281248092651, -36048.34765625), (1.91281247138977, -36067.3203125), (1.92281246185303, -36086.10546875), (1.93281245231628, -36104.703125), (1.94281244277954, -36123.12109375), (1.95281255245209, -36141.359375), (1.96281254291534, -36159.421875), (1.9728125333786, -36177.3125), (1.98281252384186, -36195.02734375), (1.99281251430511, -36212.578125), (2.00281238555908, -36229.95703125), (2.01281261444092, -36247.17578125), (2.02281260490417, -36264.23046875), (2.03281259536743, -36281.125), (2.04281258583069, -36297.86328125), (2.05281257629395, -36314.4453125), (2.0628125667572, -36344.6875), (2.07281255722046, -36381.9609375), (2.08281254768372, -36418.8984375), (2.09281253814697, -36455.49609375), (2.10281252861023, -36491.76953125), (2.11281251907349, -36531.01953125), (2.12281250953674, -36590.515625), (2.1328125, -36649.4765625), (2.14281249046326, -36707.91796875), (2.15281248092651, -36765.83984375), (2.16281247138977, -36823.25), (2.17281246185303, -36880.15625), (2.18281245231628, -36936.56640625), (2.19281244277954, -36992.48828125), (2.2028124332428, -37047.921875), (2.21281242370605, -37102.87890625), (2.22281241416931, -37157.36328125), (2.23281240463257, -37211.3828125), (2.24281239509583, -37264.94140625), (2.25281238555908, -37318.04296875), (2.26281261444092, -37370.69921875), (2.27281260490417, -37422.9140625), (2.28281259536743, -37474.6875), (2.29281258583069, -37526.03125), (2.30281257629395, -37576.9453125), (2.3128125667572, -37627.44140625), (2.32281255722046, -37677.51953125), (2.33281254768372, -37727.1875), (2.34281253814697, -37776.44921875), (2.35281252861023, -37825.3125), (2.36281251907349, -37873.7734375), (2.37281250953674, -37921.84765625), (2.3828125, -37969.53515625), (2.39281249046326, -38016.83984375), (2.40281248092651, -38063.765625), (2.41281247138977, -38110.31640625), (2.42281246185303, -38156.50390625), (2.43281245231628, -38202.32421875), (2.44281244277954, -38247.78125), (2.4528124332428, -38292.88671875), (2.46281242370605, -38337.640625), (2.47281241416931, -38382.046875))]
```

I have two tuples in this list. First I'd like to get the maximum value of the first column (eg.: (Xi,Yi), max X) of the first tuple and add that value to the first column of the second tuple. Additionally, after this operation I'd like to join the two tuples in one.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
The question has been solved. However, if instead of the first tuple I'd like to find the maximum of the first column of the `m` tuple and then add it to the first column of the next `n` tuples until the end of the list, and then at the end join all tuples in just one, how could I do it?

My code works but maybe can be optimized:

```
    indexLSNR=len(dCF3)-2
    t1max=max(dCF3[indexLSNR])[0]

    for i in range(0, len(dCF3)):
        if i<=indexLSNR:
            if i==0:
                new_line= dCF3[i]
            else:
                new_line= dCF3[i] + new_line
        if i>indexLSNR:
            new_tup2 = tuple((a + t1max, b) for a, b in dCF3[i])
            new_line= new_line + new_tup2
```

Comment: Your 2 tuples are lists of couples - what is the maximum then ? Max of the 1st/2nd value ? Max of absolute values ? Sum of the couple ?

Comment: @Emmanuel: Ok! thanks for clarifying. The added value shoudl then be the maximum of the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle any number of tuples :

```
lis = [((0.0, 0.0), (0.100000001490116, 0.0), (0.200000002980232, 0.0), (0.300000011920929, 0.0), (0.400000005960464, 0.0), (0.5, 0.0), (0.600000023841858, 0.0), (0.699999988079071, 0.0), (0.800000011920929, 0.0), (0.899999976158142, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0)), ((0.0, 0.0), (0.00249999994412065, -268.749877929688), (0.00499999988824129, -534.530700683594), (0.0087500000372529, -932.520874023438), (0.0143750002607703, -1527.93103027344), (0.0228125005960464, -2414.58032226563), (0.0328124985098839, -3408.89599609375), (0.0428125001490116, -4313.58447265625), (0.0528125017881393, -5153.6572265625), (0.0628124997019768, -6001.00244140625), (0.0728124976158142, -6861.203125), (0.0828125029802322, -7718.9912109375), (0.0928125008940697, -8568.873046875), (0.102812498807907, -9406.283203125), (0.112812496721745, -10222.2841796875), (0.122812502086163, -11016.26953125), (0.1328125, -11787.7470703125), (0.142812505364418, -12536.3466796875), (0.152812495827675, -13261.8193359375), (0.162812501192093, -13964.04296875), (0.172812506556511, -14643.01953125), (0.182812497019768, -15298.8681640625), (0.192812502384186, -15931.8173828125), (0.202812492847443, -16542.1953125), (0.212812498211861, -17130.41796875), (0.222812503576279, -17696.978515625), (0.232812494039536, -18242.431640625), (0.242812499403954, -18767.3828125), (0.252812504768372, -19272.4765625), (0.262812495231628, -19758.388671875), (0.272812485694885, -20225.806640625), (0.282812505960464, -20675.43359375), (0.292812496423721, -21107.970703125), (0.302812486886978, -21523.888671875), (0.312812507152557, -21923.1015625), (0.322812497615814, -22307.275390625), (0.332812488079071, -22677.072265625), (0.34281250834465, -23033.1328125), (0.352812498807907, -23376.078125), (0.362812489271164, -23706.50390625), (0.372812509536743, -24024.984375), (0.3828125, -24332.06640625), (0.392812490463257, -24628.27734375), (0.402812510728836, -24914.11328125), (0.412812501192093, -25190.052734375), (0.42281249165535, -25456.55078125), (0.432812511920929, -25714.037109375), (0.442812502384186, -25962.919921875), (0.452812492847443, -26203.58984375), (0.462812513113022, -26436.4140625), (0.472812503576279, -26661.74609375), (0.482812494039536, -26879.9140625), (0.492812514305115, -27091.232421875), (0.502812504768372, -27296.00390625), (0.512812495231628, -27494.9765625), (0.522812485694885, -27688.0859375), (0.532812476158142, -27875.443359375), (0.542812526226044, -28057.2890625), (0.552812516689301, -28233.853515625), (0.562812507152557, -28405.35546875), (0.572812497615814, -28571.99609375), (0.582812488079071, -28733.9765625), (0.592812478542328, -28891.48046875), (0.602812528610229, -29044.685546875), (0.612812519073486, -29193.7578125), (0.622812509536743, -29338.859375), (0.6328125, -29480.142578125), (0.642812490463257, -29617.75), (0.652812480926514, -29751.8203125), (0.662812471389771, -29882.486328125), (0.672812521457672, -30009.87109375), (0.682812511920929, -30134.09375), (0.692812502384186, -30255.271484375), (0.702812492847443, -30373.5078125), (0.712812483310699, -30488.91015625), (0.722812473773956, -30601.576171875), (0.732812523841858, -30711.599609375), (0.742812514305115, -30819.0703125), (0.752812504768372, -30924.076171875), (0.762812495231628, -31026.69921875), (0.772812485694885, -31127.01953125), (0.782812476158142, -31225.109375), (0.792812526226044, -31321.044921875), (0.802812516689301, -31414.892578125), (0.812812507152557, -31506.720703125), (0.822812497615814, -31596.591796875), (0.832812488079071, -31684.568359375), (0.842812478542328, -31770.70703125), (0.852812528610229, -31855.06640625), (0.862812519073486, -31937.69921875), (0.872812509536743, -32018.658203125), (0.8828125, -32097.9921875), (0.892812490463257, -32175.75), (0.902812480926514, -32251.9765625), (0.912812471389771, -32326.716796875), (0.922812521457672, -32400.013671875), (0.932812511920929, -32471.91015625), (0.942812502384186, -32542.44140625), (0.952812492847443, -32611.6484375), (0.962812483310699, -32679.568359375), (0.972812473773956, -32746.234375), (0.982812523841858, -32811.6796875), (0.992812514305115, -32875.9453125), (1.00281250476837, -32939.05078125), (1.01281249523163, -33001.03515625), (1.02281248569489, -33061.92578125), (1.03281247615814, -33121.75390625), (1.0428124666214, -33180.5390625), (1.05281245708466, -33238.31640625), (1.06281244754791, -33295.10546875), (1.07281255722046, -33350.9375), (1.08281254768372, -33405.83203125), (1.09281253814697, -33459.8125), (1.10281252861023, -33512.90234375), (1.11281251907349, -33565.12109375), (1.12281250953674, -33616.49609375), (1.1328125, -33667.0390625), (1.14281249046326, -33716.77734375), (1.15281248092651, -33765.7265625), (1.16281247138977, -33813.90625), (1.17281246185303, -33861.33203125), (1.18281245231628, -33908.0234375), (1.19281244277954, -33953.99609375), (1.20281255245209, -33999.26953125), (1.21281254291534, -34043.85546875), (1.2228125333786, -34087.76953125), (1.23281252384186, -34131.03125), (1.24281251430511, -34173.65234375), (1.25281250476837, -34215.64453125), (1.26281249523163, -34257.0234375), (1.27281248569489, -34297.8046875), (1.28281247615814, -34338.0), (1.2928124666214, -34377.6171875), (1.30281245708466, -34416.67578125), (1.31281244754791, -34455.18359375), (1.32281255722046, -34493.1484375), (1.33281254768372, -34530.58984375), (1.34281253814697, -34567.515625), (1.35281252861023, -34603.9296875), (1.36281251907349, -34639.8515625), (1.37281250953674, -34675.2890625), (1.3828125, -34710.25), (1.39281249046326, -34744.7421875), (1.40281248092651, -34778.78125), (1.41281247138977, -34812.3671875), (1.42281246185303, -34845.515625), (1.43281245231628, -34878.234375), (1.44281244277954, -34910.53125), (1.45281255245209, -34942.41015625), (1.46281254291534, -34973.88671875), (1.4728125333786, -35004.9609375), (1.48281252384186, -35035.64453125), (1.49281251430511, -35065.9453125), (1.50281250476837, -35095.8671875), (1.51281249523163, -35125.421875), (1.52281248569489, -35154.61328125), (1.53281247615814, -35183.4453125), (1.5428124666214, -35211.9296875), (1.55281245708466, -35240.0703125), (1.56281244754791, -35267.87109375), (1.57281255722046, -35295.34375), (1.58281254768372, -35322.4921875), (1.59281253814697, -35349.31640625), (1.60281252861023, -35375.828125), (1.61281251907349, -35402.03125), (1.62281250953674, -35427.9296875), (1.6328125, -35453.53515625), (1.64281249046326, -35478.84375), (1.65281248092651, -35503.86328125), (1.66281247138977, -35528.6015625), (1.67281246185303, -35553.05859375), (1.68281245231628, -35577.24609375), (1.69281244277954, -35601.16015625), (1.70281255245209, -35624.8125), (1.71281254291534, -35648.203125), (1.7228125333786, -35671.33984375), (1.73281252384186, -35694.22265625), (1.74281251430511, -35716.859375), (1.75281250476837, -35739.25), (1.76281249523163, -35761.40234375), (1.77281248569489, -35783.31640625), (1.78281247615814, -35805.0), (1.7928124666214, -35826.45703125), (1.80281245708466, -35847.6875), (1.81281244754791, -35868.6953125), (1.82281255722046, -35889.484375), (1.83281254768372, -35910.0625), (1.84281253814697, -35930.42578125), (1.85281252861023, -35950.58203125), (1.86281251907349, -35970.53125), (1.87281250953674, -35990.28125), (1.8828125, -36009.83203125), (1.89281249046326, -36029.1875), (1.90281248092651, -36048.34765625), (1.91281247138977, -36067.3203125), (1.92281246185303, -36086.10546875), (1.93281245231628, -36104.703125), (1.94281244277954, -36123.12109375), (1.95281255245209, -36141.359375), (1.96281254291534, -36159.421875), (1.9728125333786, -36177.3125), (1.98281252384186, -36195.02734375), (1.99281251430511, -36212.578125), (2.00281238555908, -36229.95703125), (2.01281261444092, -36247.17578125), (2.02281260490417, -36264.23046875), (2.03281259536743, -36281.125), (2.04281258583069, -36297.86328125), (2.05281257629395, -36314.4453125), (2.0628125667572, -36344.6875), (2.07281255722046, -36381.9609375), (2.08281254768372, -36418.8984375), (2.09281253814697, -36455.49609375), (2.10281252861023, -36491.76953125), (2.11281251907349, -36531.01953125), (2.12281250953674, -36590.515625), (2.1328125, -36649.4765625), (2.14281249046326, -36707.91796875), (2.15281248092651, -36765.83984375), (2.16281247138977, -36823.25), (2.17281246185303, -36880.15625), (2.18281245231628, -36936.56640625), (2.19281244277954, -36992.48828125), (2.2028124332428, -37047.921875), (2.21281242370605, -37102.87890625), (2.22281241416931, -37157.36328125), (2.23281240463257, -37211.3828125), (2.24281239509583, -37264.94140625), (2.25281238555908, -37318.04296875), (2.26281261444092, -37370.69921875), (2.27281260490417, -37422.9140625), (2.28281259536743, -37474.6875), (2.29281258583069, -37526.03125), (2.30281257629395, -37576.9453125), (2.3128125667572, -37627.44140625), (2.32281255722046, -37677.51953125), (2.33281254768372, -37727.1875), (2.34281253814697, -37776.44921875), (2.35281252861023, -37825.3125), (2.36281251907349, -37873.7734375), (2.37281250953674, -37921.84765625), (2.3828125, -37969.53515625), (2.39281249046326, -38016.83984375), (2.40281248092651, -38063.765625), (2.41281247138977, -38110.31640625), (2.42281246185303, -38156.50390625), (2.43281245231628, -38202.32421875), (2.44281244277954, -38247.78125), (2.4528124332428, -38292.88671875), (2.46281242370605, -38337.640625), (2.47281241416931, -38382.046875))]
lis = [map(list,x) for x in lis]  #create list of lists as you can't modify a tuple
maxx = max(y[0] for x in lis[:m] for y in x)     #find the max in first m tuples
for i in xrange(m,m+n+1):  #update n tuples after m
    for j in xrange(len(lis[i])):
        lis[i][j][0] += maxx
new_lis = lis[0] + lis[1]
```

Comment: Thansk! I've also introduced some code of mine. The only difference in the way my code and yours works is that in the end I want to join all tuples, not only the first and the second. Can you comment on this?

Comment: @jpcgandre `list(itertools.chain(*lis))` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

> *"First I'd like to get the maximum value of the first column of the first tuple "*

```
m = max(dCF3[0])[0]
```

or, if you prefer to be more explicit about considering only the first column

```
from operator import itemgetter
m = max(dCF3[0], key=itemgetter(0))[0]
```

> *"...and add that value to the first column of the second tuple."*

tuples are immutable so you cannot update values within it. You can however create a new tuple with the updated values:

The following creates  new tuple based on `dCF3[1]` with `m` added to the first column of all entries:

```
new_tup2 = tuple((a + m, b) for a, b in dCF3[1])
```

> *"Additionally, after this operation I'd like to join the two tuples in one."*

If you mean concatenating the two tuples into a single long tuple:

```
joined = dCF3[0] + new_tup2
```

---

**Update:**

To address your updated question, I gather from your example code that you want to:

1. Find the max value of the first column of the first column as `t1max`
2. Concatenate all the tuples into a single long tuple, but with the last `N-1` tuples (in your example, `N=2`) using updated values such that the first column is incremented by `t1max`.

Here's how I would approach it, with a view of maintaining efficiency by minimising the number of copies we make of the tuples:

```
n = 2  # your parameter
p = n - 1  # shorthand, just to make the following code cleaner
t1max = max(dCF3[0])[0]  # get max of first col of first tuple

# store a reference to all tuples except the last N-1 
# Note that we're NOT making copies of the actual tuples. Only refs.
tup_list = list(dCF3[:-p])  

# Append generators that will return the last N-1 tuples with updated values
# Again, we're not making any copies of the tuple. Only generators that will
# iterate through the tuples when consumed
for tup in dCF3[-p:]:
    tup_list.append(((a + t1max, b) for a, b in tup))

# Now we're ready to create a copy of the tuples as a single large tuple
from itertools import chain
new_tup = tuple(chain.from_iterable(tup_list))
```

p.s. If you need to support python <2.6 where [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) is not available, you could use `chain(*tup_list)` instead.

Comment: Thanks!!! Just another question: If I have more than two tuples in the list, and still want to add `m` to update the first column of the other `n-1` tuples how can I do it?

Comment: You can do it the same way but change dCF3[1] to match the index. if the number of columns are unknown, you can loop through `dCDF[1:]` and deal with each column. If you update the question (or start a new one) with more details of what you're trying to achieve I'm sure others will be happy to help.

Comment: So I need to change `new_tup2 = tuple((a + m, b) for a, b in dCF3[1])` to `new_tup2 = tuple((a + m, b) for a, b in dCF3[1:])`?

Answer (score 2):

To find the max:

```
max_col1 = map(max, zip(*dCF3[0]))[0] #[0]Gives the max of the first values in the tuple
```

To Add 1 to every 1st column in the second tuple:

```
new_tup = tuple((x + max_col1, y) for x, y in dCF3[1])
```

And to merge

```
tup = dCF3[0] + new_tup
```

Comment: @kartikr: and to add `max_col1` to first column of second tuple (dCF3[1])? Thanks

Comment: do you want to add to first column of every element in the second tuple ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick one, using `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(dCF3[0], max(dCF3[0]) + dCF3[1][0], dCF3[1][1:]))
```

This joins:

- all elements of 1st tuple
- max of 1st tuple + 1st elem of 2nd tuple
- all elemnts of 2nd tuple except the 1st one already used just before